# Oracle Stored procedure error in select

Tags: java, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

While Executing this procedure i am getting error like this. How to execute this in oracle 11g.?

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_SELECT_CUSTOMER'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

**MY Procedure is**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SELECT_CUSTOMER (
p_cust_details OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN p_cust_details for SELECT Name, Address, Contact FROM customer;
END;
/
```

Comment: show us the java side...

Comment: How are you executing your procedure? Can you post the line?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Oracle stored procedure error on select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803316/oracle-stored-procedure-error-on-select)

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B, again i am getting the error. i checked your code also. it shows the same error.

Comment: @antonio, i am executing like this begin
SP_SELECT_CUSTOMER;
end;

Comment: @sesuraj, show us what you are doing. The way I have demonstrated in my answer. Copy the content, edit your question and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

you either sending a less or more parameters than the procedure or you are sending a wrong type parameter to the procedure

Comment: check my code. i didn't pass any parameters to my procedure.